# Not getting a response for an AJAX call to PHP (with JSON data)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a PHP running on a server, and i call to it via `jQuery.Ajax()` but it always return to the error portion of it.

If i call the PHP address directly from my browser, i get the response i need, it only breaks in the jQuery call.

The PHP (simply saying) is this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['getcodenode']))
{
    echo json_encode
    (
        array
        (
            'itens'=>
            array
            (
                0=>array('id'=>100,'lb'=>'300','ds'=>'300 mm'),
                1=>array('id'=>105,'lb'=>'400','ds'=>'400 mm')
            )
        )
    );
    die();
}
?>
```

And on the javascript side i call for it like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadcall(data)
            {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    async:false,
                    method:'POST',
                    crossDomain:true,
                    dataType:'jsonp',
                    url:'http://example.com/ajax.php?getcodenode',
                    data:{'arg':data},
                    success:function(result){
                        var ret=JSON.parse(result);
                        var el=jQuery('#abc');
                        for(en in ret.itens)
                        {
                            el.Append('<div id="item_'+en.id+'">'+en.lb+', '+en.ds+'</div>');
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(result){alert('Error (loadcall)');}
                });
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="abc"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error handler has **three parameters**. Use them...

Comment: jsonp is to call to other domain different where the script javascript is hosted.

Comment: What specific error you get in your console?

Comment: In general its a `datatype mismatch` , you are trying to get JSONP while the returned data from server is JSON, this fires error on your jQuery routine, also the way you parse returned data on success is wrong...see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to read JSON objects from PHP and display in browser?

There are lots of **comments** on your code:

- While you already getting a json return from server; you don't to parse that. Its already a json object.
- You can set async:true to get a promise data
- The way you loop through objects you need to do that properly. see image how to get the object path correctly.
- You can use $ token instead of jQuery token; unless you purposely need that.
- I am not sure if this is the best approach; but it give the needed result as explained in your question.

The code is bellow tested with some comments:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    loadcall("test"); 
    // as pointed you need to call the function so it runs

    function loadcall(data) {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            method: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json', //your data type should be JSON not JSONP
            url: 'page.php?getcodenode',
            data: {
                'arg': data
            },
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result); 
                 // see attached image how to get the path for object
                var ret = result;
                var el = $('#abc');
                for (en in ret.itens) {
                    console.log(ret.itens[en].ds);
                    el.append('<div id="item_' + ret.itens[en].id + 
                    '">' + ret.itens[en].lb + ', ' + ret.itens[en].ds + '</div>');
                }
            },
            error: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

[image: How to get object path from console result?]

1. Open you **developer tool** in your browser hit <kbd>F12</kbd> (In Chrome, Firefox or Edge):
2. Go to **Console tab** and find the results.
3. Expand the results tell you get to the **object** you need.
4. Right click and **`copy property path'**.
5. Use the `object path` as needed in your code.

Comment: thanks for the return - can't use '$', for some reason it's not working, and it operates under another site, so i won't spend time checking this out - i new that, buit is someone else's problem :)

i rather keep async false, if it does not affect the result, so it would only work after return. And for the rest it did for me, it's working now

Comment: @SammuelMiranda, in this particular case `async:false` suppose to work out, it means to set to true to hold running rest of code till the result is ready, sometimes you might need it. Glad it worked out for you, regards.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call  loadcall(data)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadcall(data)
            {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    async:false,
                    method:'POST',
                    crossDomain:true,
                    dataType:'jsonp',
                    url:'http://example.com/ajax.php?getcodenode',
                    data:{'arg':data},
                    success:function(result){
                        var ret=JSON.parse(result);
                        var el=jQuery('#abc');
                        for(en in ret.itens)
                        {
                            el.Append('<div id="item_'+en.id+'">'+en.lb+', '+en.ds+'</div>');
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(result){alert('Error (loadcall)');}
                });
            }
loadcall('somethingData')
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="abc"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"...and i call to it via jQuery.Ajax() but it always **return to the error portion of it**."_ hence the function is called (anywhere but not shown in the question...)